# Schema.org (Microdata) for online application

Tags: schema.org, microdata, web-applications, semantic-web

I have a site with some onpage scripts such as "case converter" or "list sorter". I wish add microdata and I'm not sure about the right kind.
The "app" is available only on page (no download, but just a form) and is accessible via browser.
Could be the right type **Software Apps**?

Comment: Why do you want to use schema.org microdata?   I recommend only implementing it when somebody that consumes it gives a concrete benefit to your website.   For example implementing it for user reviews can get get star ratings to show in Google search.   Without knowing who is using it and what benefit you are getting from it, you are at best wasting your time and at worst making it easier for scrapers to get your content.

Comment: I whist to improve rich snippet of my pages on Google Serp. With thumbanails and user reviews.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to get thumbnails and user reviews in the Google search results using microdata.

Answer (score 1):

[**`WebApplication`**](http://schema.org/WebApplication) (which is a subtype of `SoftwareApplication`) seems to be the type you need.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebApplication">
</div>
```

To convey that the web app *is* the current page, you could use [**`WebPage`**](http://schema.org/WebPage) in addition. Either make it a MTE and use both types together, or use `mainEntity`.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebApplication http://schema.org/WebPage">
</div>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebApplication">
  </div>
</div>
```

Which one to use kind of depends on your understanding of it: "the page is the app" vs. "the app is part of the page".